# Play Vimeo Link On Roku With Ampersand

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, roku, brightscript

So I have a `Roku` channel that is completely powered by `Vimeo`. However, the other day `Vimeo` changed around some of their links that are included in the `API` call. Now, all the links have an ampersand in the URL to the videos.

In the past when we had our own CDN I could create scripts and links at will to not include an ampersand. However, I am still using the simple video player example that came with the `Roku` SDK examples and for some reason video links with ampersands will not play.

Is there something in the `Brightscript` code that I need to change to play links with ampersands?

How can I change this channel around to work with video URLS that contain ampersands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, i cannot think of a reason why Roku won't load files with & in the URL.

But i have a suspicion the reason may be somewhere else: do you by any chance pass the content (list of videos etc) to the player as XML? You should make sure ampersands in text and attribute values for XML are escaped to `&amp;` - otherwise `roXmlElement.parse`(xmlText) acts unreasonably. And by "unreasonably" i don't mean it loses the & or shows error, rather it silently drops whole elements or subtrees.

Pro tip: if parsing XML on Roku and suspecting something might have got lost in parsing, use myXmlElem`.genXML()` to dump it back to console.

Comment: You, my friend, are absolutely awesome! You not only explained "the what" of the situation but also "the why". Per your explanation and recommendation, I changed the output of the XML file to convert "&" to "&amp;" and it now works like a charm. Thank you so much!